# Написать запрос sql при помощи оконной функции

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица в postgres - `Сотрудники` с атрибутами - `ид`, `год`, `фамилия`, `зарплата`.

Нужно написать запрос, который выводит атрибуты - `год`, `фамилия`, `зарплата`, и последним столбцом сумму зарплат, при этом сначала нужно вывести сумму зарплат.

Должна выводиться так - сначала выводится сумма зарплат по возрастанию для каждой конкретной фамилии, а потом сумма зарплат для каждого года.

Примерно это должно выглядеть так:

| год | фамилия | зарплата | сумма зарплат |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | Иванов | 20000 | 20000 |
| 2011 | Иванов | 25000 | 45000 |
| 2010 | Смирнов | 15000 | 15000 |
| 2011 | Иванов | 22000 | 37000 |
| 2010 |  |  | 750000 |
| 2011 |  |  | 1500000 |

Как это можно вывести одним запросом? Возможно, нужно использовать оконные функции или есть другие варианты?